# RestructuredText Hyperlink to Line Number

Tags: hyperlink, restructuredtext

I am writing a FAQ page in restructuredtext and I would like to place a list of questions at the top with links to the answers further down the page. I wrote the following but the link doesn't go anywhere. What am I doing wrong?

> `How are you associated with the University? `_

How do I create a hyperlink to a line number in reST?

Answer (score 2):

I just found it here: http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/rst/quickref.html#example-callout

If you wrap the question in backquotes like this:

> `How are you associated with the University?`_

then below you can reference the question like this:

> .. _How are you associated with the University?:

Now, when you click on the question link it takes you to the correct line, all without using HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Put anchor link tag on your your question:

```
<a href="/donate/faq#n281">How are you associated with the University? </a>
```

...

Here is your answer:

```
<a id="n281"></a>
... Your n281 answer  ...
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without creating a new div for each answer? I was hoping for a solution in reST with a hyperlink that points directly to the line of the answer so future questions and answers could be easily added without dealing with the HTML.

Comment: Yes, you can use anchor tag instead, I will edit my post